# How to add HTML form inside of accordion

Tags: javascript, html

I have this basic accordion, but I want to add a html form in it. So when you open the accordion, the form will be inside of it. I can do it as a variable, but I want to have the HTML form inside of the body tag. Not sure on how to do that.

function:

```
    var showDate = new Date();
      var year = showDate.getFullYear();
      var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
      function drawTable(forDate) {
        var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
        var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
        var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
          var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
          table.appendChild(newRow);
          for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
            var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);
            var textarea = document.createElement("button");
            textarea.setAttribute("class", "row");
            newRow.appendChild(textarea);
            textarea.innerHTML = day1;
            var textarea1 = document.createElement("div");
            textarea1.setAttribute("class", "panel");
            newRow.appendChild(textarea1);
            textarea1.innerHTML = "the HTML form should be here, inside of the accordion";
            cellsToDraw--;
          }
        }
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
          acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            panel.style.width = "0";
          } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
          panel.style.width = "100%";
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <h1 id="displayingMonth"></h1>
    <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse"></table>
    <form id="form" action="insert.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="message" value="" placeholder="Message">
      <br>
       <input  type="submit" name="" value="Send">
     </form>
```

All help is appriciated! :)

Comment: What you mean by "inside the body tag" ? all of this code is inside the body tag...

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I guess I was a bit unclear! I mean that I dont want the form in the script as a variable, I want it separerade from the script.

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put the HTML you want in a hidden div and use it as the innerHTML. Then forget width and height to control the accordion and use display directly. Here try this:

```js
var showDate = new Date();
var year = showDate.getFullYear();
var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

function drawTable(forDate) {
    var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
    var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
    var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
            var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);
            var textarea = document.createElement("button");
            textarea.setAttribute("class", "row");
            newRow.appendChild(textarea);
            textarea.innerHTML = day1;
            var textarea1 = document.createElement("div");
            textarea1.setAttribute("class", "panel");
            textarea1.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
            newRow.appendChild(textarea1);
            textarea1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('form').innerHTML;
            cellsToDraw--;
        }
    }
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.display == 'block') {
              panel.style.display = 'none';
          } else {
              panel.style.display = 'block';
          }
       });
    }
}
drawTable(showDate);
```

```html
<h1 id="displayingMonth"></h1>
<table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse"></table>
<div style='display: none'>
<form id="form" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" value="" placeholder="Message">
    <br>
    <input  type="submit" name="" value="Send">
</form>
</div>
```

Now you should style the whole thing with css to make it more presentable. I guess you can move on from here.

**EDIT**

After thinking a bit in what you wanted I found a simple way to do it. Please check the edited answer.
But in order to separate the HTML from the javascript the best would be to use a templating framework. I use and recommend Nunjucks (https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) but there are plenty. You can also use Require.js for example and include it as a file.